# Подключение boost к qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qtcreator

Доброго времени суток.
Уже долго сижу, бьюсь над такой проблемой: собрал драйвера MongoDB и BSON из под компилятора от пятнадцатой вижуалки и даже заставил собираться под qt. Вот только для их работы необходим boost. Сначала пытался просто показать ему, где находятся хедеры. Не помогло. Собрал тем же компилятором, пытался подключить либу из папки system, как рекомендовали в соседнем топике. Не помогло. Пытался подключить все либы разом из ".../stage/lib". Не помогло.
Идеи кончились.
Файл .pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mngProj
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


#LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib
#LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/mng_driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/mng_driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxxd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/liblibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/liblibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d.lib
```

Ошибка:

```
E:\Projects\qt\mngProj\mng_driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\stdx\string_view.hpp:37: ошибка: C1083: Не удается открыть файл включен­ие: boost/utility/string_ref.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/`

Comment: Такая строчка уже присутствует

Comment: @user3573700, тогда полный путь попробуйте пропишите, без `PWD` и двоеточий

Comment: Это я тоже пробовал

Comment: @user3573700, тогда проверьте, что по этому пути действительно есть этот заголовок. Чудес ведь не бывает в разработке, если Вы говорите, что всё так сделали, то этой ошибки не будет.

Comment: @user3573700, ещё попробуйте полностью очистить директорию, в котороую qmake нагенерировал файлы и пробуйте сделать чистую сборку. Только очищайте не из qtcreator, а руками.

Comment: Все заголовки он видит и они браузятся. Т.е. я получаю всплывающие подсказки от IDE, когда пробую подключить один из хедеров буста. По моему опыту это значит, что проблема с либой. Потому что, когда такая же ошибка вылезала для драйвера монго оказалось, что проблема была в том, что скомпилирован драйвер был msvc14, а в qt была только msvc13, пришлось qt переустановить со свежим компилятором.

Comment: @user3573700, компилятор не видит заголовка. Причём тут либа? До линкера ещё дело не дошло.

Comment: И тем не менее. Это почему-то помогло. Почистил старые билды. Пошли другие ошибки. Буду смотреть. Спасибо.

Comment: И тут я понял, почему это помогло: он стал собирать билд в другую папку, так как поменялся компилятор...

Answer (score 0):

Итак, огромное спасибо @ixSci. Я так и не понял почему, но приходится удалять билд, собранный qt creator, вручную. Проект успешно прошел стадию линковки со следующим файлом .pro:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbson-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbson-static-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongoc-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongoc-static-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbsoncxx
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongocxx

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += E:/local/boost_1_59_0/
DEPENDPATH += E:/local/boost_1_59_0/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxx

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/libbsoncxx.lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -llibmongocxx

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/libmongocxx.lib
```